# How to parse text to json from a API that returns text using Python

Tags: python, json, rest, python-requests

I am calling a Rest API that seems to only return text.
example

> gma:AciX8_0002    hypothetical protein

I want to get the data in json.
in Postman, I tried to add a header content-type  application/json  but still get text.
Does that mean the Rest API is unable to return json?

In that case , in python , do i need to manually build the json file , like this :

```
       list = []
        try:
            with open(realfilename, "r") as reader:
                for line in reader:
                    if line.strip():  # fix problem: do not parse empty lines
                        singleline= json.loads(line)
```

Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 1):

The header `Content-Type` is a way for the api endpoint or the information provider to tell the information consumer i.e. your program what kind of data does it send, so that your program can decide how to process this data. There is another header specification called the HTTP `Accepts` header that your program supplies in its request telling the api-endpoint of what kind of data that you are able to consume. Maybe you need to add this header to your request, but any dependence of the data format from the api endpoint on this request header is purely implementation specific and you should consult the api documentation to get the full picture.

If you do not have the source of the api or if you are not in control of it, you can not generally control the format of data that it will send you, so you have to resort on manually parsing it suite your needs.

Comment: I was worried that you'd say that :-(  I tired accpet and no luck. Thank you for confirming.